# Groovy Script with XmlSlurper

Tags: groovy, xmlslurper

I have an XML file that I am trying to parse through with Groovy.

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
    <ServerList>
        <Server>server1.me.com</Server>
           <CleanUpTest>TESTING</CleanUpTest>
        <Server>server2.me.com</Server>
    </ServerList>
```

This code works and gives me the output Result: [server1.me.com]:

```
def serverList = new XmlSlurper().parse("E:\\Program Files(x86)\\Jenkins\\jobs\\first_servers.xml")

def output = []
serverList.Server.find { it == 'server1.me.com' }.each{
     output.add(it)
}

return output
```

But when I try to get the value in CleanUpTest it is not working.

```
def serverList = new XmlSlurper().parse("E:\\Program Files(x86)\\Jenkins\\jobs\\first_servers.xml")

def output = []
serverList.Server.find { it == 'server1.me.com' }.CleanUpTest.each{
     output.add(it)
}

return output
```

What do I have wrong?  I am expecting Result: [TESTING]

Comment: `CleanUpTest` is not a child of `Server`, it's a sibling.

Comment: Yup, just poor formatting.

Comment: Is xml you attached correct? or realistic data that match your xml.

Comment: I appreciate the help and that pointed me to my error.  I created the XML incorrectly and adjusted it.